# Modify these CSS tabs?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am absolutely in love with these CSS tabs:

https://codepen.io/ekscentrysytet/pen/QbNdEB

However, I have a tab set up right now that is really simple.  I click on a tab, and it takes me to another page.  Sample code:

```
<div class="top">
   <ul id="tabnav">
      <li class="tab1"><a href="Inventory.aspx">Search</a></li>
      <li class="tab2"><a>Description</a></li>
      <li class="tab3"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAcqusitionValue" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="lnkAcqusitionValue_Click">Acquisition/Value</asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li class="tab9"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAudit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="lnkAudit_Click">Audit Info</asp:LinkButton></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I determine which tab I am on by using the body tab of the HTML page, like this:

```
<body class="background" id="tab2" onload="document.Form1.txtAssetDescription.focus()">
```

If it's not a herculean task, could someone show me how to get the look of the tabs I linked, but possibly use a simple setup like I am currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with other tabs.  Thanks for the -1 for my question!